# @PropertySource returns 'Properties location not resolvable: (No such file or directory)'

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-properties

I have a config file that is meant to use @PropertySource to set values. However it seems like it is not working (below)

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource(value = "file:/Users/myUser/etc/secrets/credentials.json",
                ignoreResourceNotFound = true),
        @PropertySource(value = "file:/Users/myUser/etc/secrets/secret.id.properties",
                ignoreResourceNotFound = true)})
public class SpringConfig {
    @Value("${secret.id}")
    private String projectID;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    public String getId() {
        return env.getProperty("secret.id");
    }
}
```

I have set up dummy files in /Users/myUser/etc/secrets and have defined both credentials.json and secret.id.properties files.
However when I run the application and call the config file's getId() method, it returns the id that is defined in the application.properties file, not in the @PropertySource path '/Users/myUser/etc/secrets/secret.id.properties' I suspect it can't find the path. (same for credentials.json)
But the path file is definitely correct.

By the way, the inside of secret.id.properties file is:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.bigquery.project-id=project-id
```

How can I have the code actually fetch from the files in etc/secrets/ instead of from my applications.properties (or have my secrets/secret.id.properties be put into `spring.cloud.gcp.bigquery.project-id=${spring.cloud.gcp.bigquery.project-id}` in my application.properties?

I also tried to define in my applications.properties file

```
spring.cloud.gcp.bigquery.project-id=${secret.id}
```

and tried

```
spring.cloud.gcp.bigquery.project-id=${spring.cloud.gcp.bigquery.project-id}
```

but they both don't work and gives me an error.

I also checked file path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stack over flow community.

I have tried running your sample code here assuming you are providing absolute path in value field of @PropertySource.
You have configured the annotations correctly, and everything spring is doing is as expected.

To understand what is happening, we need to understand the order of external properties which gets considered by [spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

You are putting properties in 2 places:

1. external file (credentials.json & secret.id.properties not named as `application.properties or application-{profile}.properties`)
   2.`application.properties` inside your jar

So as per order of preference of property, `application.properties` in your jar gets precedence over the external property not named as `application.properties` (credentials.json & secret.id.properties i.e. @PropertySource annotations on your @Configuration classes.).

To verify this, you can comment out property in `application.properties` in your jar, and the properties from external files will be loaded.

Comment: I have commented out the properties in application.properties, and have also renamed the file to app.properties (so it doesn't use the file's properties). Either way did not work, and the application was not able to detect the other properties files in @PropertySources

Comment: If you want to read the `spring.cloud.gcp.bigquery.project-id` property from file, in getId method you should replace `env.getProperty("secret.id");` with `env.getProperty("spring.cloud.gcp.bigquery.project-id");`. Can you also post the complete stack trace?

Comment: I get the error, 'Properties location [file:/Users/myUser/etc/secrets/secret.id.properties] not resolvable: /Users/myUser/etc/secrets/secret.id.properties (No such file or directory)' which does not make sense since it does exist, and I have already accessed it before with this path

Comment: are you using spring mvc or spring-boot?

Comment: I am using spring-boot

Comment: I am also getting 'Cannot invoke "org.springframework.core.env.Environment.getProperty(String)" because "this.env" is null
' now

Comment: are you running your application using command line? if so you can add: -Dspring.config.additional-location=file:///Users/myUser/etc/secrets/

Comment: I eventually was able to get the PropertySources working, also helped to comment out the properties in application.properties and force the app to get from my properties files i defined. Thank you for your help!